# Trouble understanding posterior probabilities

Tags: posterior, hidden-markov-model

I'm having trouble understanding what this problem is asking for. Could someone clarify how to obtain posterior probabilities using backward/forward probabilities?

[image: Problem]

Comment: Clarify notation please. Say, what does $f_F(2)$ represents (in words) -same for the rest. Also, which is the "second state"? Finally I feel there is a slight inconsistency in the impression that the verbal description of the set up leaves, and the probabilities shown in the diagram. The text talks about "occasionally switching to a loaded die" -which is validated by the $F\rightarrow L$ probability of only $0.05$. But once we are in the "loaded die state", there is a $0.9$ probability that we will stay there... this is much stronger than an "_occasionally_ dishonest" casino!